# autopunctuation not working properly

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, context, context-mkiv

What am I doing wrong?  According to my understanding, these two formulae should look different (the second one should have a thin space):

```
\setupmathematics[autopunctuation=yes]

\starttext

$(2,5)$ versus $(2, 5)$

\stoptext
```

(I am using ConTeXt MkIV.)

Comment: In math mode, TeX is set to ignore any discretionary spaces it finds in the input.

Comment: @Mico LuaTeX is involved here, so there is/should be a callback to alter the behaviour I think (if you check the code, the option sets an `\attribute`).

Comment: @JosephWright -- thanks for setting me straight on this issue.

Comment: Even in MkII, it is (or at least I think so) supposed to take this space into consideration.

Comment: @mbrok: Looks like a bug in the current implementation. Please report it to the ConTeXt mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `autopunctuation=yes` *did* was make the comma behave the same as the period --- suppress the automatic thin space, for the benefit of those who use the comma as a decimal mark. Since last monday's beta, however, `autopunctuation` has the behaviour you expect: when it is set to 'yes', `2, 5` will get a thin space, and `2,5` will not. I have written a complete [overview of autopunctuation settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85367/2229) over at the question [Number kerning in ConTeXt math mode is different and worse than normal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85367/2229).